# How to make a filter with composite key

Tags: oracle10g

I want to make a filter in which it check if all department status =Y then return the emp_code of that record all department mean filter check value from 1-4 and also match the status=Y

**dept_id and emp_code is composite key**

[image]

I make this query but it not return desire result

```
select distinct(emp_code) from fsc_sts_dpt where dept_id in (1,2,3,4) and status= 'Y'
```

But the issue is dept_id 1,2 where emp_code=101010 is empty so in operator also consider 101010 but I want if any status with respect to dept_id is null it will not appear in the output.

Comment: Is it MYSQL or Oracle? Fix your tags.

Comment: can you put a sample of what is the expected output you seek ?

Comment: I removed three tags from your question. [tag:join] didn't apply at all, [tag:sql] is very broad, and the tag excerpt suggests using a more specific tag instead, and [tag:oracle] clearly states it is about the Oracle RDBMS and not about other products (like MySQL). Please pay attention when adding tags.

Comment: ok i remember it in future thanks

Comment: What is your desired output? Is it just `150021` and `151015` (since these have `status=Y` for all rows)?

Comment: yes yes 150021 and 151015 i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> check if all department status =Y then return the emp_code of that record all department mean filter check value from 1-4 and also match the status=Y

This will, firstly, find only those `emp_code`s where all the entries have a `status` of `'Y'` (regardless of the `dept_id`) and will, secondly, check that those `emp_code`s have at least one `dept_id` with the values `1,2,3,4`.

```
SELECT emp_code
FROM   (
  SELECT   emp_code,
           COUNT( CASE WHEN dept_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) THEN 1 END ) AS num_depts
  FROM     fsc_sts_dpt
  GROUP BY emp_code
  HAVING   COUNT( CASE WHEN status = 'Y' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END ) = 0
)
WHERE num_depts > 0
```

If you just want to check that the `status` is `'Y'` for all `dept_id IN (1,2,3,4)` then you can simplify it to:

```
SELECT   emp_code
FROM     fsc_sts_dpt
WHERE    dept_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
GROUP BY emp_code
HAVING   COUNT( CASE WHEN status = 'Y' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END ) = 0
```

Comment: please can u justify this  COUNT( CASE WHEN status = 'Y' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END ) = 0 how count equal to zero i am little confuse with this

Comment: `COUNT()` will not count `NULL` values; so when `status='Y'` then the `CASE` expression returns `NULL` and the row is not counted and for all other rows (including `NULL` status values) the `CASE` returns 1 and the row is counted. So, if `COUNT(...) = 0` then all the rows will have `status='Y'` and if `COUNT(...)>0` then there will be at least one row where `status IS NULL OR status <> 'Y'`.

Comment: You could also write it as the negation of the previous case expression like this: `HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN status IS NULL OR status <> 'Y' THEN 1 END ) = 0`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want...

```
SELECT emp_code
FROM fsc_sts_dpt
GROUP BY emp_code
HAVING count(*) = count (CASE WHEN status='Y' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

Comment: but the issue is dept_id 1,2 where emp_code=101010 is empty so  consider 101010 but i want if any status with respect to dept_id is null it not appear in output  you query also consider 101010

Comment: yeh that awesome please explain your query i want to understand it

Comment: `count(*)` is the only aggregate function which consider NULLs. It means that for `emp_code=101010` you will have `count(*)=4`, because you have 4 rows with `emp_code=101010 `. `count (CASE WHEN status='Y' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)` counts only rows where `status='Y'` because if status is not 'Y' you will get NULL and `count(column)` doesn't consider NULLs, it means, that for `emp_code=101010 `count(status) will be 2, because only two rows have not null status

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select emp_code
from fsc_sts_dpt
where status = 'Y'
and dept_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by emp_code
having count(*) = 4
```

As `dept_id and emp_code is composite key` there wont be two occurrence of same `dept_id` and `emp_code`, so count will be `4` means `dept_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)` and `status = 'Y'`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems You want a simply select where status is = 'Y'

```
select distinct(emp_code) from fsc_sts_dpt where ifnull(status,'N') ='Y' ;
```

or

with your last comment

```
select distinct(emp_code) from fsc_sts_dpt 
where dept_if not in (select distinct dept_id from  
                             fsc_sts_dpt is null) ;
```

Comment: i already try this check description i modify description before a minute

Comment: I have update the answer.. ifnull now don't match ...and is this not work i ad eventually another check.

Comment: dear if null not valid in oracle any idea it raise an error

Comment: You have mysql in tag but for oracle .. use NVL(..)

Comment: NVL(status,'N') = 'Y'

Comment: The question wants to `check if all department status =Y` - this will return those values where at least one `status=Y` (and could have some rows where `status<>Y`) but it won't check that all the rows have `status=Y`.

Comment: You mean you want only the department where there aren't  any row with status null? please confirm..